# Export selected sheets into separate PDF files

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, export

I need to export selected sheets in my workbook to separate PDF files.

The code below exports the whole selection of sheets into one PDF and duplicates the PDF with different sheet names.

```vb
Sub ExportAsPDF()

Dim Folder_Path As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select Folder path"
    If .Show = -1 Then Folder_Path = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

If Folder_Path = "" Then Exit Sub

Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
    sh.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Folder_Path & Application.PathSeparator & Range("RD").Text & " " & sh.Name & " 2024.pdf"
Next

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: One of the few places where `Select` is warranted.  Just add `sh.Select` after your `For Each...` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportAsPDF()

    Dim Folder_Path As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select Folder path"
        If .Show = -1 Then Folder_Path = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    If Folder_Path = "" Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet, n As Long
    For Each sh In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        sh.Activate
        sh.Select
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, _
        Folder_Path & Application.PathSeparator & Range("RD").Text & " " & sh.Name & " 2024.pdf", _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=True
        n = n + 1
    Next
    MsgBox n & " Sheets Exported"

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `sh.Activate`  statement. `sh.Select` alone works fine.

Comment: I know your solution works - but why isn't `sh.Select` changing the Collection we are Looping through? - is the collection that is looped through a duplicate that was created when the loop started, or where am I missing something?

Comment: @Lord Yes, the parameter to the iterator is like ByValue not ByRef.

Comment: Wow, it worked, thank you a lot! It works with sh.Select alone just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim selectedWorksheets As New Collection

For Each sh In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
    selectedWorksheets.Add sh
Next sh

For Each sh In worksheets
    sh.Select
    sh.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Folder_Path & Application.PathSeparator & sh.Name & " 2024.pdf"
Next sh

'// The following part resets the Selection to what it was at the start of this procedure (remove if not needed)

Dim i As Long
Dim worksheetNames As Variant

i = 1
ReDim worksheetNames(1 To selectedWorksheets.Count)

For Each sh In selectedWorksheets
    worksheetNames(i) = sh.Name
    i = i + 1
Next sh

ThisWorkbook.worksheets(worksheetNames).Select

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```